# Plot_ly in R: How to add proper axis labels and tick-values?

Tags: r, r-plotly

If `M` is a matrix, then

`plot_ly(z = M) %>% add_surface()`

plots a surface plot of that matrix. Meaning, rows and colums are x and y values, and the z-value is the element in the matrix.

However, the x and y axis are labeled as integers corresponding to the rows and columns of `M`. Further, the axis are just called "x" and "y" literally on the plot.

But this isn't what I want. The matrix `M` has been generated using `outer(A, B, someFunction)`, where `A, B` are vectors. So I actually want the axis to display the values `A` and `B`, and I want the axis labels to say `"A", "B"` as opposed to `"x", "y"`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `A` and `B` in `x` and `y`:

```
library(plotly)

A <- B <- seq(-5, 5, by = 0.2)
z <- outer(A, B, function(x,y) exp(-x^2-y^2))

plot_ly(x = A, y = B, z = z) %>% add_surface() %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "A"), yaxis = list(title = "B")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Found from their documentation here: https://plot.ly/r/figure-labels/

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

M <- 
  matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 1), ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

plot_ly(z = M) %>% 
  add_surface() %>% 
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "A"), yaxis = list(title = "B")))
```