# Label axis in plot_ly()

Tags: r, plotly

I try to add labels to the axis but the only way I found is [Plot_ly in R: How to add proper axis labels and tick-values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210643/plot-ly-in-r-how-to-add-proper-axis-labels-and-tick-values) but the z-values there are somehow constructed via a matrix (and a function or so) whereas I am simply using columns from a dataframe. Thus, `add_surface()` seems not to work. My plot code looks like this:

```
plot_ly(x = df_experiment$T, y = df_experiment$rH, z = df_experiment$V
              , type = "contour"
              , autocontour = TRUE
              , contours = list(coloring = 'heatmap', showlabels = TRUE)
              ) %>% colorbar(title = "V/ kV") "rH")))
```

Comment: can you post dput(df_experiment)

Comment: also which axis did you want to label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works (you might want to post your data):

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 21:30,
  z = 3:12
)

plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z
              , type = "contour"
              , autocontour = TRUE
              , contours = list(coloring = 'heatmap', showlabels = TRUE)) |> colorbar(title = "Hi Ben")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was it just the way I defined x, y and z within plot_ly()?

Comment: no, it wasn't that (you can test it by replacing ~x, ~y, and ~z by df$x, df$y, and df$z). It seems to have been some strangeness in the color_bar bit (it's unclear what `"rH")))` is doing)